# What is the easiest way to define a complex number in exponential form in maple?

Tags: complex-numbers, math-software, maple

What is the easiest way to define a complex number in exponential form in maple?
Is there a built-in function?

eg: $\underline{Z} = 600 \cdot e^{-j45^\circ}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple works in radians.

Maple is very happy to work with expressions of the form $\tt 5*exp(I*Pi)$.

For example:

$$\tt Re(5*exp(I*Pi));$$

$$\tt -5$$